# scanf and printf format modifiers

Tags: c, string, printf, modifier

I need help on this exercise from C Primer Plus.

**Write a program that requests your first name and does the following with it:
Prints it in a field three characters wider than the name**

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
int main()
{
    char a[40];
    int p,v=0;
    printf("Enter your first name: \n");
    scanf("%s",a);
    p= strlen(a);
    v==p+3;
    printf("%s",a);
}
```

I cant figure out how what to use as a modifier for the width
what should I add in between % and s?

Comment: my name is "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890 nop nop nop jmp 0x70002345"

Comment: "*Prints it in a field ...*": Shall the name be right aligned or left aligned in the field?

Comment: what @GradyPlayer wants to say: you have a buffer overflow, wher the name you enter is longer than 40 characters. You should be aware of ALWAYS restrict the input to the max length of your reserved memory!

Comment: Use `if (scanf("%39s",a) != 1) Handle_NoValidInput()`.  `39` prevents buffer overflow mentioned by @Peter Miehle and Grady Player.  The maximum width of non-space `char` to scan is 39 and code needs 39 `char` + 1 (for the `'\0'`) to save it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is one way to do it:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>

int main()
{
    char a[40];

    printf("Enter your first name: \n");
    scanf("%s",a);
    printf("[%-*s]", (int)(3 + strlen(a)), a);

    return(0);
}
```

The printf() function can do it all.

From the question code, it is clear that "`%s`" as a format string is understood.

A format string of "`%*s`" allows the caller to place the (space-padded) width to be specified.  For example:

```
printf("%*s", 10, "Hello");
```

The above will print "`Hello`" (as expected), in a 10-character frame.  Hence, the command above actually prints: "     `Hello`".

To put the spaces on the other side, tell printf() to left-justify the string using:

```
printf("%-*s", 10, "Hello");
```

This results in printing: "`Hello`     "

Comment: +1 I was wondering why the cast `(int)`, but now understand its need as `strlen()` returns type `size_t` which may exceed `int`. Do recommend checking `scanf()` result.

Comment: The code still assumes that the entered name will be less than 39 characters.  Therefore, the scanf() should include a size limit on the format string.

Answer (score 5):

the goal of this excercise is to read and grok the manual page for printf(). The reading part could only be done by you and there is no shortcut. The format specifier is the most complex chapter in C-Programing (other would say 'pointer'), and it is very wise to know where look things up (man-page) in need of remembering.

When you are done reading, you should have a little (or big) understanding of the format-specifier %s with all its possibilities.

EDITH: when you are done reading, and there is still a question whether to use "%*.*s" or "%s" or "%-.*s" etc., please come back with an updated question.

Comment: It's the answer the OP needed to hear.  There's no shortcut to learning the most complicated parts of the C language.  +1